# How to change IsReadOnly by Trigger

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, triggers

can anybody enlight me way the following doesn't work

i'm using the mvvm pattern 
after executing my code i'm still able to check and uncheck the Checkboxes in my DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Property (part of my ViewModel)

```
    public bool noCheckPermission
    {
        get { return false; } // just as example
    }
```

Xaml (my View no code behind)

```
<DataGrid Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Itemlist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCheckBoxColumn}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding noCheckPermission}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding noCheckPermission}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>    
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="60" 
                                    Header="Freigabe" Binding="{Binding FreigegebenL}" CanUserReorder="False">
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>               
            </DataGrid.Columns>                
        </DataGrid>
```

Edit:
after doing what blindmeis and Will suggested. I got this as my current XAML

```
 <DataGrid Height="300" Margin="12" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  x:Name="grd" ItemsSource="{Binding Itemlist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" TabIndex="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="60" IsReadOnly="{Binding  DataContext, Path=noCheckPermission, ElementName=grd}" Binding="{Binding FreigegebenL}"
                                    Header="Freigabe"  CanUserReorder="False">
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>               
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and this as Error in my Output Window:
*`System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=noCheckPermission; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCheckBoxColumn' (HashCode=35155182); target property is 'IsReadOnly' (type 'Boolean')`*

Comment: `//just an example` uh, without seeing that code nobody can help you.  Its the change notification on the property that triggers the data trigger.  Without change notification for your properties in the view model changes to the property won't show.  Without that code, we can't tell if you have this or not.

Comment: @Will i also use this fix value (there is no logic at the moment ... )

Comment: Understood.  Next thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: @Will it looks like it doesn't get called but all my other Properties work fine i also triple check the spelling (thats the last thing i could figure out yesterday) at Tuesday i will test your suggestion i also will snoope it maybe in find something

Comment: @Will i get nothing in my output window that had anything to do with a DataBinding problem do you know how to debug a trigger?

Comment: @Will ok after some trying i got an error see Edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**first**
i noticed that my property was in the wrong VM (it was in the Child VM which are my rows) fixing this doesn't solved my problem

**finally**
after reading [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) i was able to solve it

## in condensed form

### class

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

### XAML

**Resources**

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

**Column**

```
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="60" Header="Freigabe"  CanUserReorder="False"
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding Data.noCheckPermission, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" 
                            Binding="{Binding FreigegebenL}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the DataGridCheckBoxColumn to be readonly, you should add your style to your DataGridCheckBoxColumn.

```
<DataGrid Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
      x:Name="grd"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Itemlist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                    
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="60" 
                                Header="Freigabe" Binding="{Binding FreigegebenL}" CanUserReorder="False">
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCheckBoxColumn}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.noCheckPermission, ElementName=grd}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.noCheckPermission, ElementName=grd}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>    
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>               
        </DataGrid.Columns>                
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: i don't know if you understand what i'm trying to do so i will explain it to you i wane change the value of the `IsReadOnly` Property depending on an property(`noCheckPermission`) from my ViewModel after some trying with `IsReadOnly="{Binding noCheckPermission}"` i read that this doesn't work so i tried again but now with triggers

Comment: i think the problem is that your first have to apply your style to your column and then you have to change your binding because, nocheckPermission is on your viewmodel and not on the item from ItemList.

Comment: ohh good advice i will test in on Tuesday, but i'm sure it will work so meanwhile +1

Comment: ok sadly it doesn't work i can't even snoop the IsReadOnly Value